# Can you pass a variable as part of a JSON chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been looking around Stack Overflow and Google and haven't been able find an answer to this. I have a JSON file which has presidents are level one keys (sorry if this is the wrong terminology, I mostly work with Python). Each president has a bunch of data associated with each one. However, I want to only return information for the president a user enters. I have tried doing the following, to no avail:

```
var foo = json.presidents[pres]foo
```

and

```
var foo = json.presidents. + pres + .foo
```

Where 'pres' is the variable I have stored the user inputed president's name. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first way is missing the dot.

```
var foo = json.presidents[pres].foo;
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks, that took care of it. Feel sort of silly for not trying that, but I'm new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way:

```
var foo = json.presidents[pres].foo;
```

And by the way it's not  a json file and actually it's not even a json, it's simply a javascript object.

Comment: This will not work if `foo` is not a variable (though json.presidents[pres]["foo"] will). The square brackets essentially mean "Evaluate whatever is inside as a string, and then access the property of this object with that name".

Comment: @SavageWolf, I understood from the question that foo is a string variable, I'll edit.